# Category Display for Tasks in Evolution

Tags: email, evolution

I'm syncing an Exchange account to Evolution. I like to group my tasks by category, but Evolution seems to want to treat multiple categories as its own group. For instance, let's say I have three tasks, one with category "Foo", one with "Bar", and one with both "Foo" and "Bar". The display that Evolution gives me is this:

```
Categories: Foo
Task 1

Categories: Bar
Task 2

Categories: Foo,Bar
Task 3
```

But what I want is

```
Categories: Foo
Task 1
Task 3

Categories: Bar
Task 1
Task 3
```

Is there a way to make the display do this?

Thanks in advance to the community for all of their help!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Tasks created on evolution, are categorized, Clich on Tasks->click on 'any category ' button, then you have your tasks displayed in categories which you have earlier created the task under specific categories.